# Javascript execute function on Woocommerce checkout event

Tags: javascript, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I need to wait for the checkout to be updated when the billing country is changed before I can run some AJAX calls on Woocommerce.

```
jQuery('select#billing_country').change(function(){
       $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function( e, data ) {
         //AJAX calls here
        });
});
```

The problem is some of these calls then update the checkout as well and this results in an infinite loop.
Is there a way to just wait for the checkout to be updated once (only the first time) every time the billing country is changed? So something like this:

```
jQuery('select#billing_country').change(function(){
       $when.firsttime( 'updated_checkout', function( e, data ) {
         //AJAX calls here
        });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does .one() get rebound to the event every time the billing country is changed again or does it stay unbound? If it's the former then I think this will be the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function is performed only once after the checkout is updated thanks to the **`updated_checkout`** event.

Therefore:

1. The `#billing_country` field is changed
2. The AJAX `update_checkout` (not "updated") call is executed to update the cart
3. Once the checkout is updated (with the **`updated_checkout`** event) the custom AJAX calls are made (only if the `checkout_is_updated` variable is false).

The `checkout_is_updated` variable is initialized to "false" each time the entire page is updated.

```
// executes one or more instructions only once after checkout has been updated
jQuery( function($) {
    // set a control variable
    var checkout_is_updated = false;
    // if the "#billing_country" field changes, update the checkout
    $('form.checkout').on('change', '#billing_country', function(){
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        // after the checkout has been updated
        $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
            // just once
            if ( checkout_is_updated == false ) {
                /*
                    * AJAX calls here
                */
                checkout_is_updated = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code has been tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However this is not what i want to do, I would like the  code to run once the checkout has been updated and only once as  I use $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout'); within.